Find angle x in this quadrilateral (no calculator allowed)
The problem you see below is from the same person behind the "Find the angle x"-problem I posted some days ago, which was solved using this elegant solution posted earlier today.
I've been told by the person that no calculator is allowed to solve it.
Problem:
Find angle x in the following figure.


So, can you solve it using no calculator? (Trig is allowed as long as you don't use calculator, but I would prefer a geometrical only solution).

What have you tried? Please show your attempts

@SohamSaha I have looked at this problem for quite some long and besides getting the trivial angles BAC and BDC I don't see how to proceed.
